# Optimized solutions for the Apollonius problems

Tags: soft-question, education

I'm looking for some material which tries to solve the Apollonius' tangency problems with the least amount of constructions possible, but I couldn't find any. Does anyone know some material which makes this analysis?

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ApolloniusProblem.html#:~:text=Given%20three%20objects%2C%20each%20of,the%20hardest%20involves%20three%20circles.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_Apollonius

Comment: https://www.jamieyorkpress.com/wp-content/uploads/bsk-pdf-manager/2017/03/Tangent-Problem-of-Apollonius.pdf

Comment: https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath113/kmath113.htm

Comment: none of those answer my question

Comment: The comments weren't meant as an answer. Just more relevant input for the question.

Comment: ok, my concern is about minimizing the constructions itself not about calculations with real numbers and stuff